# Правильное сокращение «байт» и «бит»

Tags: существительные, информатика

Как правильно сокращать слово «байт»?

В английском языке, обычно принято использовать заглавную букву «Б» для «байт», и строчную букву «б» для «бит».  По-русски будет по-другому?

Например, почему товарищи из Sun Microsystems так не делают, когда пишут по-русски: https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/space_maps_russian

> Для файловой системы в 1Гб битовая карта займет 32Кб -- её можно держать в оперативной памяти и довольно быстро сканировать для поиска свободного пространства. Для файловой системы в 1Тб размер битовой карты составит уже 32 Мб -- такой объём ещё можно уместить в оперативной памяти, но это уже нетривиально в смысле размера и времени сканирования. Битовая карта для файловой системы в 1Пб потребует уже 32Гб, и уже просто-напросто не поместится в оперативной памяти большинства машин. Следовательно, сканирование битовой карты в этом случае потребует её чтения с диска, который намного медленнее оперативной памяти.

Comment: В русском использование большой и маленькой буквы в этом случае ничем не отличается от английского, если эти товарищи так написали, значит они не вполне грамотные.

Comment: @Yellow Sky это вы неграмотный, большие буквы в русском языке используются только для единиц измерения, названных по имени людей. А по ссылке всё грамотно написано.

Comment: @Anixx Это только для единиц СИ, а для компьютерных это не так.

Comment: Дело даже не столько в том, насколько уместно отступать от традиции обозначать заглавными буквами те единицы, что названы в честь людей. А в том, что и латинская, и кириллическая «бэ» заглавная *была занята задолго до байтов* — так обозначается логарифмическая единица — _бел_ (Б); да она едва ли когда встречается без приставки _деци-_ — _децибел_ (дБ), но тем не менее.

Answer (score 6):

В области компьютерных единиц измерения остается много подобных несоответствий, поскольку это инженерная дисциплина, а не научная. Поэтому номенклатура исторически создавалась похожей на научную, но с научной точки зрения развивалась "неправильно".

В последнее время есть последовательные шаги в сторону стандартизации номенклатуры (например новые названия "кибибиты" и "кибибайты" вместо с научной точки зрения неправильных "килобитов" и "килобайт"), но не все внимательно за этим следят. В целом русские обозначения ориентируются на английские, т.к. именно английский язык является законодателем мод в области IT.

Что же касается блогов и прочих "самописных" ресурсов, то ожидать 100% грамотности и точности в употреблении терминов ожидать не приходится, ведь текст не проходит через руки корректоров, редакторов и научных редакторов перед публикацией.

Если же обратиться к документации, то например действующий [ГОСТ 8.417-2002](http://pribor.info/docs/?start=0&action=obj&objid=82476&relid=3) не приводит однобуквенного сокращения для слова "бит", оно должно писаться как "Кбит":

[image: таблица единиц информации и их сокращений]

А ниже приводится такое примечание (обратите внимание что слово "байт" указано целиком):

> Исторически сложилась такая ситуация, что с наименованием „байт“ некорректно (вместо 1000 = 10<sup>3</sup> принято 1024 = 2<sup>10</sup>) использовали (и используют) приставки СИ: 1 Кбайт = 1024 байт, 1 Мбайт = 1024 Кбайт, 1 Гбайт = 1024 Мбайт и т.д. При этом обозначение Кбайт начинают с прописной буквы в отличие от строчной буквы „к“ для обозначения множителя 103.

Так что согласно ГОСТу для байт нужно писать **Кбайт** или **КБ**, а для бит - только **Кбит**.

Солидарна с ГОСТом и Википедия: [КБ - "килобайт"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82), [Кбит - "килобит"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82).

Впрочем, внимательный читатель обратит внимание что приложение "А" ГОСТа не обязательное, а рекомендованное, что, конечно, не позволяет сказать что нужно писать только так, а не иначе.

---

Очень хорошая статья описывающая историю путаницы с байтами и битами есть на [сайте Артемия Лебедева](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/84/). Он достаточно обоснованно утверждает что путаница в обозначениях активно используется в рекламных целях (попробуйте "пораскачивать" в рекламных целях систему СИ). В конце статьи приводятся "правильные аббревиатуры" для единиц измерения информации: для Кбайта - КБ, для Кбита - Кб. Там же можно увидеть и такие аббревиатуры как кБ (десятичный килобайт = 1000 байт) и кб (килобит - 1000 бит).

Впрочем, хотя мнение Лебедева является достаточно влиятельным, вряд ли можно ссылаться на него как на официальный источник. Очевидно также что Лебедев за основу правильных аббревиатур взял англо-американский стандарт.

---

Вот в этом учебнике информатики биты и байты вообще не сокращаются: Кбайт и Кбит: [Информатика 7-9 кл. А. Г. Кушниренко и др.](http://www.niisi.ru/kumir/books/2.pdf). К сожалению не удалось найти что по этому поводу думают составители ЕГЭ, но похоже что их мнение тоже может не совпадать с ГОСТом.

---

Раз уж не удалось найти рекомендации в авторитетных источниках, обратимся к словарям. Вот подборка статей про значение слова мегабайт:

[Научно-технический энциклопедический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ntes/2664/%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%93%D0%90%D0%91%D0%90%D0%99%D0%A2):

> МЕГАБАЙТ (обозначается **Мб**), в вычислительной технике - единица объема информации, равная 1024 килобайт. Часто используется для выражения объема компьютерной памяти или запоминающего устройства. Иногда мегабайт округляют до 1 млн. БАЙТ.

Яндекс.Словари › Издательский словарь. — 2003:

> МЕГАБАЙТ — единица емкости памяти или длины записи, равная 1024 килобайтам. Упрощенно под М. понимается также значение 103 килобайтов или 106 байтов. Сокращенная форма М. — Мбайт.

[Энциклопедия Кольера](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_colier/6035)

> КОМПЬЮТЕР устройство, выполняющее математические и логические операции над символами и другими формами информации и выдающее результаты в форме, воспринимаемой человеком или машиной.
>   ОЗУ работают быстро: микропроцессор может получать доступ к ним за 10-20 нс. Обычные коммерческие модули ОЗУ хранят до 256 **Мб** (1 Мб равен 1 048 576 байт).

[Финансовый словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/fin_enc/24944)

> Мегабайт
>   Мегабайт - единица измерения объема передаваемой или хранимой информации. 1 Мбайт = 1024 Кбайт.
>   По-английски: Megabyte
>   Синонимы:  Мбайт, Мб
>   Синонимы английские:  MB

Как видим сокращение **Мб** используется чаще чем **Мбайт** (а **МБ** вообще не удалось встретить). Некоторые словари (в частности полиграфический) утверждают что мегабайт можно сократить до М, а килобайт до К (например "объемом 64К"). Так что единства нет и среди словарей, но вариант **Мб** в технических словарях явно более предпочтительный.

Не знаю, можно ли считать его авторитетным источником, но [справочник В. П. Леонтьева (2004)](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hpxWY6xL8pQC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82+%22%D0%9A%D0%B1%22+%22%D0%9C%D0%B1%22+%22%D0%93%D0%B1%22&source=bl&ots=ShoTw50f2Q&sig=0t3y8TlcKqTPoddM9Mw91TVx65Y&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=pKdSUoCLC4OC4gS_roHABg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) автора многочисленных книг на компьютерную тематику также использует строчную "б" для байт:

[image: Персональный компьютер. Карманный справочник.]

Что же касается сокращения бит - все словари единодушны - "бит" не сокращается, а пишется целиком - Кбит, Мбит, Гбит. Так что несмотря на статью Лебедева, все авторитетные источники не позволяют сокращать бит до одной строчной "б". Что же касается байт, то ГОСТ предписывает сокращать его до прописной Б (КБ, МБ, ГБ), а словари приводят то же сокращение со строчной б (Кб, Мб, Гб).

Comment: Большие буквы в русском языке используются только для единиц измерения, названных по имени людей.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на ГОСТ. Большая "К" чтобы отличать "информационную" приставку (х1024) от приставки "кило" (х1000).

Comment: На земетку: вышеуказанная статья на blogs.oracle.com явно была написана профессиональным техническим переводчиком -- блог является официальным ресурсом какого-то главного программиста/менеджера, он, скорее всего, вообще по-русски не говорит; очень уверен, что такую же номенклатуру они используют и в печатной документации (если таковая имеется).

Comment: @cnst Похоже что многие энциклопедические словари тоже предпочитают строчную "б" для сокращения слова "байт". А слово "бит" вообще всегда приводится целиком. Вот только чем они руководствуются - не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Когда речь идет о единицах, производных от байта, в пишут строчную букву б:

```
5 Гб = 5 гигабайт
5 Мб = 5 мегабайт
```

Когда речь идет о единицах, производных от бита, пишут "бит" полностью:

```
5 Гбит = 5 гигабит
5 Мбит = 5 мегабит
```

Сами бит и байт пишут полностью:

```
5 бит
5 байт
```

Меня так в школе учили. Так что, в вашем примере всё написано правильно.